# Removing everything after ',' or '.' in a string - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Although I checked the answers on StackOverflow, I am not sure hot to apply it on my specific case:

```
Select s.saleno, s.comments,
case 
    when Charindex('held by', s.comments) > 0 
    then substring(s.comments, Charindex('held by', s.comments)+8,40)
    else null end as TrimmedText,
FROMsales s
JOIN push p 
ON p.saleno = s.saleno
WHERE Charindex('held by', s.comments) > 0;
```

**The issue is that I get result like:**

```
CompanyTwo, due ti
CompanyThreeee.
CompanyLong, is a scan 
CompanyShort, originally dated 01/01/2000
CompanyTTT.
CompanySomething, due 02/01/2010.
```

**The result I need:**

```
CompanyTwo
CompanyThreeee
CompanyLong
CompanyShort
CompanyTTT
CompanySomething
```

I always want to keep "Company[...]" up until it meets a dot or a comma. Always a dot or a comma appears after this string.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you please add one comment in full text as an example. Plain text "as is" and expected result, thx

Comment: Hello @Shnugo ! Thank you for trying to help me out.
I edited the body for a better understanding of the output and the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robert, your comment made it clear. Here you are:

Paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(txt VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('CompanyTwo, due ti')
,('CompanyThreeee.')
,('CompanyLong, is a scan')
,('CompanyShort, originally dated 01/01/2000')
,('CompanyTTT.')
,('Company without something')
,('CompanySomething, due 02/01/2010.');

SELECT pos.*,pos2.*, LEFT(txt,(CASE WHEN pos2.Comma<pos2.Dot THEN pos2.Comma-1 ELSE pos2.Dot-1 END)) AS YourCompany
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT ISNULL(CHARINDEX(',',t.txt),100000) AS Comma
       ,ISNULL(CHARINDEX('.',t.txt),100000) AS Dot
) AS pos
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT CASE WHEN pos.Comma=0 THEN 100000 ELSE pos.Comma END AS Comma
       ,CASE WHEN pos.Dot=0 THEN 100000 ELSE pos.Dot END AS Dot

) AS pos2
```

Comment: Oooook :) I will try to make this work and understand the way it was built.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @Robert, It's not that difficult: Find the position of comma and dot. If it is not found, CHARINDEX comes back with 0. Second step: Set 0 to a high value. Last step: use LEFT to  the smaller of the two positions, If helpful, please vote up and mark as accepted, thx!

Comment: @Shungo Ok, I understand. It seems that this works really well. I discovered other issues in the database with it. Can you please explain how can I repeat the DOT and COMMA case if instead of those I have other things? I see now that it can be followed by 2 strings as well:

Company1 was dropped
Company2 is validated

I would need to repeat the DOT and Comma thing with "was dropped" and "is validated"

Comment: @Robert, so your "Always a dot or a comma appears after this string." in your question comes out to be wrong? How many other chars are there? Which chars? The biggest challenge ist the "take the smallest" because there is not MINIMUM function. With many more I'd simulate a table, and query it with `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY pos`

Comment: @Shungo yes, my statement seems to be wrong but I understood the idea so I think this is good enough and I can make my way through. One final question: Is it possible to use wildcards in the 1st argument of CHARINDEX ?

Comment: @Robert, no, no wildcards... You could have a look at RegEx but this is to fat probably... please vote up if you don't mind...

Comment: @Shungo I tried voting but I am not allowed yet as I still need some reputation.

Comment: @Robert, helped you to help me ;-)